# What type of mixin allows to transform both X and Y?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to implement a class **using the sklearn classes** to convert both X and Y.
But in the sklearn source code I can only find the X transform (for example, kernelPCA):

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dbac82d362f296dc2746f10e43ffa1615660/sklearn/decomposition/kernel_pca.py

Definition:

```
class KernelPCA(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin)
```

How this class (which transforms both X and Y) should be organized? And from which sklearn classes should it inherit?

Comment: What kind of class do you want to create?

Comment: @hellpanderr It is to scale both X and Y. It can easily be achieved by using "StandardScaler" twice, but one class(with fit and transform functions) is necessary to add possible solution to TPOT(tool for evolutionary search of sklearn pipeline): https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot